# Why say amen to b'rich shmei before taking out the Torah on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, prayer-book, torah-service, amen

Usually we do not say amen to our own bracha. So why do we sing amen before taking out the Torah on Shabbat? (Bei ana rachetz... Amen)  The amen is even printed in the siddur (Art Scroll).

Comment: I sense that the reasoning is similar to why we say "Amen" to each paragraph of Kaddish. It's not limited to just brachot, obviously.

Comment: @DanF  What is the reason for saying amen in kaddish?

Comment: @DanF Is Brich shmei a bracha?

Comment: The text of "Brich Shmei" comes from Zohar, and the "Amen" is part of that text. I'm surmising that considering that the first words of the par. are "Brich Shmei" which means "Bless the name", it seems very close to the start of a common bracha that starts "Baruch atah Hashem". So, perhaps, it is considered a bracha. But, again, consider that the response "Amen" is not just after a bracha, as mentioned, above. So, I don't find it so unusual that a "non" bracha would have it.

Comment: As a side note one should take out the Torah and then Brich shmeay should be said ,not after it said,see the Igros Moshe and Rivevos Ephraim

Comment: If it is part of the text, why do many siddurim omit it or put it in parentheses? And if it is a bracha, why would we say it after our own bracha? In Kaddish, it is not acting as an agreement with a bracha but almost a commentary or directive about proper behavior.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=1456&CategoryID=530), it is a request, not a blessing, and the *Amen* said at the end is also a request, "May these words be fulfilled".